# Why did Lovett invite Rose aboard his search boat in Titanic?

Tags: plot-explanation, titanic

The opening to Titanic shows Rose "Dawson" watching a TV news report of Brock Lovett's ship searching the Titanic wreckage.  She then makes a phone call to Lovett during which a private conversation ensues.  The next scene shows Rose arriving on Lovett's boat by helicopter, with pets and many personal affects.

Why did Lovett invite her to come in person?

Clearly Lovett believed she had valuable information about where he might find the diamond he was seeking.

But why was her visit to his boat necessary to exchange such information?

Given that she possessed the diamond at the time of the phone call, she must have been either very vague over the phone, or she outright lied to Lovett. If she was vague, why did he invite her on board, at such great expense?

Did he invite her and her daughter and pets on board just to hear her love story?  She never even made any mention (that I know of) to Lovett about the location of the diamond.

So... **What was the arrangement that lead Rose to Lovett's search boat?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lovett, obsessed with the Titanic and the *"Heart of the Ocean"*, has been searching for the diamond for three years and the time and money for his expedition were running out, so he clearly is in a difficult position. His investors want to call off the search if he does not come forward with any progress soon.

When they find the picture showing a woman wearing the diamond **the day the Titanic sunk**, he realizes that after years of searching this is the greatest shot he ever had on finding out the location of the diamond.

So in the light of this great discovery, the cost of flying Rose in and interviewing her personally is nothing compared to the expenses this expedition probably devoured in the previous months tapping in the dark.

As you said, it is likely that Rose bargained her way into the flight, offering information/her story in exchange for seeing the Titanic and especially her picture again. It is unlikely that she had a hard time convincing Lovett though, because he wouldn't want to risk missing important details by disgruntling his only contemporary witness and he probably was eager himself to hear the story from face to face.

So the main factor for this deal was the fact that Lovett was running out of time.

Of course it seems a little bit unfair from Rose's side to lie about the diamond, knowing exactly that this is what Lovett and his crew are searching for for years. She carries it with her the whole time, and finally drops it into the ocean to find closure for herself while she could help a man struggeling for his "career".

On the other hand with her story she changed Lovett's view on the Titanic and her history. He was so obsessed with the diamond that he never thought about the real meaning of the events and the disastrous impact it had on so many lives:

> Three years, I've thought of nothing except Titanic; but I never got it... I never let it in.

So it might be argued that while she did not help him find the diamond, she helped him find something better: the true story behind the Titanic.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that even a desperate man in Lovett's situation would spend that kind of money to bring Rose aboard, without some sort of promise of a return.  But it is a work of fiction... so I'm sure your answer is as close to correct as anyone will come up with.

Comment: *"Rose .. carries it with her the whole time, and finally drops it into the ocean to find closure.."* Since I mentioned this very answer on [Why did Rose throw the diamond necklace overboard?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21728/566) I thought you were due a link.  :)